# Populate the observable property of one object when list is generated from another

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to populate the observable property of one object when the list from which I select is generated from another.  The options for the select are a property of `$root.Rider`, while the selected option is a property of `$root`.

If I use `value: selectedContract` in the binding for the select tag (as in the sample), selecting an option changes `selectedContract`, but a preset `selectContract` is not selected on load.

If I change the value to `value: payment_contract().option_value` and add `optionsValue:'option_value'`, the preset is populated on load but `selectContract` is not updated when selecting from the options list.

Code:

```js
$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedContract = ko.observable();
   self.rider = new Rider({
        id: 11
    });
    contract = new Contract({
        terms: 'Terms 2',
        account_id: '2',
        account_name: 'Account 2'
    });
    self.selectedContract(contract)
};

//Rider
function Rider(data) { //charge options and prepaid options are arrays of contract objects
    var self = this;

    self.id = data.id;
    self.contract_options = ko.observableArray();
    //populate contract_options for demo
    var contract = new Contract({
        terms: 'charge',
        account_id: '1',
        account_name: 'Account 1'
    });
    self.contract_options.push(contract);
    contract = new Contract({
        terms: 'charge',
        account_id: '2',
        account_name: 'Account 2'
    });
    self.contract_options.push(contract);
    contract = new Contract({
        terms: 'charge',
        account_id: '3',
        account_name: 'Account 3'
    });
    self.contract_options.push(contract);
}

function Contract(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.terms = data.terms;
    self.contract_id = data.contract_id;
    self.account_id = data.account_id;
    self.account_name = ko.observable(data.account_name);
    self.option_value = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.account_id + '|' + self.contract_id;
    });
};
```

```html
<select name="contract_id_charge" data-bind="options: rider.contract_options, 
    value: selectedContract, 
    optionsText: 'account_name',
    optionsCaption: 'Select Charge'
"></select>
<div data-bind="with: selectedContract">
    <div>
        <label>Terms:</label><span data-bind="text: terms"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Account Id:</label><span data-bind="text: account_id"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Account Name:</label><span data-bind="text: account_name"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6mwxq9g/15/)

Comment: Can you please simplify your question. It's very difficult to understand. I would post a small section of your model and view and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I simplified as much as I could and added code to the post.  The linked fiddle is functional, and has a bit more context.

Comment: Your question is even longer now. Can you please explain simply in one line, what the issue is?

Comment: Please try to narrow your questions down to a **minimal** example that demonstrates the problem, rather than simply posting what appears to be the entirety of your project's code as a JSFiddle.  It's much easier for others to help you if they're not reading several hundred lines of code for the relevant bits.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know what is and isn't relevant.  This actually is a tiny portion of the project, and I have already removed a portion with which I have experienced "side-effects" when trying to fix the option list.  The issue is complex.  Perhaps not a question for SO, but I don't know where else to go.

Comment: Yeah; if you can't narrow your issue down to a small section of the code, it's not a SO question it's a "please fix my code for me".

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're misusing the `value` data-binding on your `<select>` tag.

With the `<select>` tag, the `options` binding specifies the list of options, and the `value` data-binding should specify an observable to hold the value of the currently selected option.

Instead, you have: `value: payment_contract().option_value`, which is a read-only computed; rather than being an observable to hold the selected contract.  If you specify `value: payment_contract`, the selected contract will be stored in the Ride's `payment_contract` observable, as desired.

Also, the `optionValue` binding specifies, for a given option, what value should be stored in the observable designated by the `value` binding.  You're using some string based on the account_id and the contract_id; but it seems more likely that you'll just want to store a reference to the entire Contract object; rather than a string representation, so that binding can probably be omitted.

The following ` tag seems to work:

```
<select name="contract_id_charge" 
    data-bind="options: rider().charge_options(), 
        value: payment_contract,
        optionsText: 'account_name',  
        optionsCaption: 'Select Charge'
    ">
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks.  This solved one problem, but now the preset `payment contract` is not selected on page load http://jsfiddle.net/k6mwxq9g/14/.

Answer (score 0):

I tried my best to answer given how complicated you made the question. Instead of using optionsValue binding for your select, just use the value binding. This can then be bound to an observable which will be populated with the selected option from charge_options.

```
<select name="contract_id_charge" 
data-bind="options: contract_options(), 
    value: selectedContract, 
    optionsText: 'account_name',
    optionsCaption: 'Select Charge'
"></select>
<div data-bind="with: selectedContract">
    <div>
        <label>Terms: </label><span data-bind="text: terms"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Account Id: </label><span data-bind="text: account_id"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Account Name: </label><span data-bind="text: account_name"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedContract = ko.observable();

    self.contract_options = ko.observableArray();

    //populate contract_options for demo
    var contract = new Contract ({
        terms: 'Terms 1',
        account_id: '1',
        account_name: 'Account 1'
    });
    self.contract_options.push(contract);
    contract = new Contract ({
        terms: 'Terms 2',
        account_id: '2',
        account_name: 'Account 2'
    });
    self.contract_options.push(contract);
    contract = new Contract ({
        terms: 'Terms 3',
        account_id: '3',
        account_name: 'Account 3'
    });
    self.contract_options.push(contract);
};

function Contract(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.terms = data.terms;
    self.contract_id = data.contract_id;
    self.account_id = data.account_id;
    self.account_name = ko.observable(data.account_name);
    self.option_value = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.account_id + '|' + self.contract_id;
    });
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x6appqz0/